# Inheritance in model causing unintended consequences

Tags: c#

This is my model:

```
public class ManageEngineSite
{
    public string accountName { get; set; }
    public string siteName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ManageEngineUpdateSite : ManageEngineSite
{
    public string oldSiteName { get; set; }
}
```

When I instantiate a new object based on the ManageEngineUpdateSite model:

```
    ManageEngineUpdateSite sitetoUpdate = new ManageEngineUpdateSite();
    siteToUpdate.accountName = test1;
    siteToUpdate.description = "test description";
    siteToUpdate.siteName = "Site Name";
    siteToUpdate.oldSiteName = "Old Site Name";
    Operation responseModel = Test.UpdateSite(siteToUpdate);
```

If I set a breakpoint at the last line of code and inspect the object, it has an object modeled like this:

[image]

I believe this is breaking my code as the object that is getting passed is seemingly missing oldSiteName.

How do I use inheritance on my model but still resolve this problem?

Comment: It isn't missing *oldSiteName*. Your object is still of type *ManageEngineUpdateSite*

Comment: you are best to STEP THROUGH the code - not just place a breakpoint. perhaps "Test.UpdateSite" is what is causing the siteToUpdate object to change

Comment: Is `Test.UpdateSite` only expecting a `ManageEngineSite`?  If so, then `oldSiteName` won't be accessible in that function without casting to `ManageEngineUpdateSite`.  It's not entirely clear what you're asking

Comment: _"I believe this is breaking my code"_ You believe _what_ is breaking your code? _"the object that is getting passed is seemingly missing oldSiteName."_ What do you mean? It's right there in the screenshot. How is it missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't have a problem. As shown in your snapshot, your object DOES have the property `oldSiteName`. It's jsut shown in the debugger in a slightly different place to remind you that it's a property of the `ManageEngineUpdateSite`object, and not an inherited property.

Now, maybe your `Test.UpdateSite` method accepts a `ManageEngineSite` as its argument. To access the property, you will have to do a cast.

```
var siteToUpdateAsManageEngineUpdateSite = siteToUpdate as ManageEngineUpdateSite;
if (siteToUpdateAsManageEngineUpdateSite != null)
{
    var oldsiteName = siteToUpdateAsManageEngineUpdateSite.oldsiteName;
    // Do things
    ...
}
```

That's not a really clean way of doing it though, maybe you should add an override to `Test.UpdateSite`.

```
UpdateSite(ManageEngineUpdateSite siteToUpdate)
{
    // Do generic things
    UpdateSite((ManageEngineSite) siteToUpdate);

    var oldsiteName = siteToUpdate.oldsiteName;
    // Do specific things
    ...
}
```

It's pretty hard to tell with so little info about what you're trying to do.

Comment: could the one who downvoted please elaborate a little on why he did so?

Comment: Thank you for explaining this - I understand why this is happening now. I'm rather new to C# but starting to get put off posting here with beginner questions as they either get down voted or mocked by the C# elite.

Thank you for being the person who puts the effort into explain, it's much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I too think SO would be a far better place with less eliticism. We were all beginners once.